# Spring boot Postgresql And MongoDb Data Sync

Tags: spring, spring-boot

im working in spring boot API and im connected to Postgres And MongoDB, the idea of the app is  Postgres is used to store data and MongoDB for reading data(full-text search) , my issue is that i want to know what's the best way to synchronize data between Postgres and MongoDB. for example, when I persist my user object in Postgres i want to replicate this raw in MongoDB . what I plan to do is to save the same object twice using spring data (Post api) but I'm not sure if it will a good idea to synch data in my java code.

this is an example of my model :

```
@Table("users")
public class User{
    @Id
    @Column("user_id")
    private Integer id;
    
    //..

@Document(collection = "users")
public class UserDocument {

    @Id
    private String id;
    
    //...
```

anyone can guide me what's the best way to achieve this data sync please?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I wouldn't handle this in code, I would probably configure a kafka sink to take writes into Postgres and send them to Mongo.

With that said, I assume that you have a service layer that's performing these writes to Postgresql.  I don't see any reason why immediately after writing to Postgres, you can't persist it to Mongo as well.  Placing them in the same service method allows both operations to participate in the transaction too.

Comment: @Iane.maxwell thanks for our response. but im not sure if undestand the second part of your answer since you said you wouldn't handle this in code !

Comment: @James I was simply stating that if you must do it in code, just do both writes in the same service method so they both participate in the transaction.

Comment: @Iane.maxwell i got you . thanks a lot

Comment: i create a global save method in mu service that calls the the save method of both repository postgres and mongo.. should i add @Transactional  annotation my global save method?

Comment: @James Yes, annotate the method with `@Transactional`, else a transaction will be created and committed for each of your save operations.